# Can i add two elements at once in a list comprehension?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, list-comprehension

The output i want:

```
[[(1,1)], [(2,2)], [(2,2)], [(4,4)], [(3,3)], [(6,6)]]
```

This is the code that does not work:

```
mylist = [[[(x,x)], [(x*2,x*2)]] for x in range(1, 4)]
```

I know i could use:

```
mylist = []
[mylist.extend([[(x,x)], [(x*2,x*2)]]) for x in range(1, 4)]
```

But is there a way to write this in one line?
I my script the code is a bit more complicated, the example above is just to show the principe. Therefore it makes no sense.

Comment: `[x*e for x in range(1, 4) for e in range(1, 3)]`

Comment: @deceze just a detail, but I think OP wants `[[x*e] for …]`

Comment: mylist = [[x*y] for x in range(1, 4) for y in range(1, 3)]

Comment: @BrutusForcus Thank you for the answer, i realised that i asked too unclear. I changed it slightly.

Answer (score 1):

Use a nested list comprehension:

```
mylist = [y for x in range(1, 4) for y in ([x], [x * 2])]
print(mylist)
```

Result:

```
[[1], [2], [2], [4], [3], [6]]
```

Comment: Or `[[(y, y)] for x in range(1, 4) for y in (x, x * 2)]` for the output the OP wants, in their _current edit_.

Answer (score 1):

you can use builtin `itertools`

```
>>> from itertools import chain

>>> list(chain.from_iterable([[(x, x)], [(x*2, x*2)]] for x in range(1, 4)))
[[(1, 1)], [(2, 2)], [(2, 2)], [(4, 4)], [(3, 3)], [(6, 6)]]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to solve this with a list comprehension without using `itertools.chain. from_iterable`, you can use nested list comprehension to unpack the list that you create for each iteration.

This is done as `[item for sublist in list for item in sublist]`

Applied here -

```
[j for x in range(1, 4) for j in ([(x,x)], [(x*2,x*2)])]
```

```
[[(1, 1)], [(2, 2)], [(2, 2)], [(4, 4)], [(3, 3)], [(6, 6)]]
```

This is equivalent to using the unpacking operator `*` over the `[[(x,x)], [(x*2,x*2)]]`, but since that doesn't work in a list comprehension, this is a good way to do the same.